# Is there a way to add an "else" statement to COUNTIFS function in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, datatable

I have a excel formula with COUNTIFS to count the number of values with certain conditions, but if there is nothing to count or if the total number of values is 0, it just shows up as blank. I was wondering how to add an else statement so that if there are no values or 0 values it would display 0 instead of just blank

```
=COUNTIFS(Table22[Report Deadline],"<=" & TODAY()+7,Table22[Report Deadline],">=" & TODAY())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

`=COUNT(FILTER(Table22[Report Deadline],(Table22[Report Deadline]>=TODAY())*(Table22[Report Deadline]<=TODAY()+ 7),""))`

It first filters and then counts the relevant dates.

Comment: I realized that my issue was very silly, I went to File>Options>Advanced>display options for this worksheet>show a zero in cells that have a zero value. But this solution does work thank you